# How to set vcores for sqoop job

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, sqoop, sqoop2

How does sqoop aquires vcores for execution. I submit a sqoop job with 4 mappers and the application starts with 1 vcore even when there are around 50 vcores available. So there is no parelllization. This is an import sqoop job into text file. These are the configuration paramaters in yarn with respect to vcrore allocation. How does a sqoop job acquires vcores for execution?

```
<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>4</value>
<source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
<value>1</value>
<source>mapred-default.xml</source>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores</name>
<value>1</value>
<source>mapred-default.xml</source>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
<value>8</value>
<source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores</name>
<value>1</value>
<source>mapred-default.xml</source>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>1</value>
<source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>1</value>
<source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism

> Sqoop imports data in parallel from most database sources. You can specify the number of map tasks (parallel processes) to use to perform the import by using the -m or --num-mappers argument.

Map tasks are the same as to vcores.

Comment: Thanks. I dd provide --num-mappers to 4 and the behavior I could se is some times I get parallelism with 4 vcores assigned 1 for each mapper) and some time application gets only 1 vcore(even when there are more than 1 vcore available) there by each mapper runs one after another. I couldn't figure out why this happens.